# Libreoffice writer bypassing Linux file permissions

Tags: permissions, libreoffice

I have a file marked as read-only:

```
ls - l | grep 400.IntoTheShelterOfTheCabin.odt 
-r--r--r-- 1 stephen stephen  27K 2020-07-22 08:11 400.IntoTheShelterOfTheCabin.odt
```

Yet LO Writer will save changes to that same file.

- The file has been closed,
- All running instances of Writer killed.
- Writer restarted to open the file

And yet writer will save changes to the file.

I start writer with a script using this command :

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice --writer --norestore --nolockcheck $filename
```

From https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters

```
--norestore Disables restart and file recovery after a system crash.

--nolockcheck  Disables check for remote instances using the installation.
```

I run the script under my UID.
I am the owner of the file.
I have full permissions on the parent directory.

Running `writer` without those flags makes no difference.

How is this happening? Is it expected behavior?

Comment: are you the owner of the file? If you log in as a different user do you get the same result?   Please [edit] with the additional information.

Comment: What's the permission setting on the parent directory? `ls -ld .`. LO Writer is probably deleting and recreating the file. You could see this with `iwatch`.

Comment: @waltinator Yes thank you.. That is exactly what's happening. I have a `pyinotify` process watching the directory for another purpose and see that LO is creating a temporary file and then moving that temporary file to the target file. However this process must require the deletion of the original file -- marked read only. No?

Comment: It is possible to delete a read-only file if you have read/write permissions on a directory the file is in.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour if I start Libreoffice as user, it shows a warning "read-only" as I open the file and doesn't let me overwrite it. If I want to save, it asks for a new file name.
But if I run it as root using `sudo libreoffice`, then it doesn't show any warning and just overwrites.
Don't assume that you run it as root, so still not quite clear what may cause it for you.

Comment: @palto Not running as root@ Hm. I start Writer with a script that I run under my own UID without sudo. I've added that script to the question.

Comment: @StephenBoston Tried your script, still same behaviour for me that `writer` doesn't allow me to overwrite the read-only file.